# Whats the memory cost of using all static methods in a struct/class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Does creating a lot of `static`/`class` functions in Swift `class`/`struct` result in unreleased memory when the iOS app is running? Is it a good practice to use `static`/`class` functions for Utility classes?

How different is the memory cost between using `static`/`class` functions in Swift and using

```
+ (void) someMethod;
```

in Objective-C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does creating a lot of static/class functions in Swift class/struct result in unreleased memory when the iOS app is running?

`static` and `class` methods are compiled into your code and will increase your application's size in storage. They won't necessarily increase the application's memory usage, if they're never used. Since `static` methods can't be overridden like `class` methods, they can always be statically dispatched. This allows the compiler to better optimize them. In many cases, simple static methods can even be inlined into the place they're called from. It's as if their method body was transplanted directly into the call site.

> Is it a good practice to use static/class functions for Utility classes?

Typically it's a good idea to avoid utility classes. Most things that would typically go in a utility class in languages like Java or C# can be done much more nicely with extensions in Swift. `fileprivate` global functions are also handy when you need a utility function that's only used in a single file. You should only create utility classes if you're you have functions that you would like to use across multiple files or modules.

> How different is the memory cost between using static/class functions in      Swift and using
>
> ```
> + (void) someMethod;
> ```
>
> in Objective-C?

And that's the Objective-C syntax for a class method. Objective-C does not support static methods.

Comment: I believe static methods in let's say C++ and class methods in Objective-C are the same thing. With all differences in runtime organization, it's the same concept.

Comment: @Andy No, static methods in C++ have no equivalent in Objective C. Static virtual methods in C++ are the equivalent of class methods in Objective C.

Comment: @Andy The important difference is that static, non-virtual methods can't be overridden. Objective C has no such equivalent.

Comment: @Alexander - Sorry for a very late response. Thanks a lot for the clarification, you gave me a lot of good pointers to read on. On your second answer, the question is really to understand how different is an objective-C class method vs Swift class method? Any additional pointers to read on this topic?

Comment: @RP Objective C's and Swift's class methods are conceptually identical. The only real difference is that Swift also supports static methods, in addition to class methods.